# See values of Class methods in Scala

Tags: class, scala

I'm brand brand new to Scala, but I'm having trouble debugging my stuff. I have this "test" in a book I'm reading to make a `Family` class with a `familySize()` method. My solution was something like:

```
class Family(names:String*) {
  def familySize():Int = {
    args.length
  }
}
val family1 = new Family("Mom", "Dad", "Sally", "Dick")
family1.familySize() is 4
```

However, this produces an error:

```
scala:8: error: value is is not a member of Int
family1.familySize() is 4
                     ^
one error found
```

My problem is, I have no idea how to see what `args.length` equals. I tried just doing `family1.familySize()` but when I run it it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` doesn't exist, it's `names`:

```
class Family(names: String*) {
  def familySize(): Int = names.length
}

val family1 = new Family("Mom", "Dad", "Sally", "Dick")
println(family1.familySize()) // will output 4
```

You can also avoid curly braces around `names.length` being a one-liner.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the question answered, if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Can't yet. Need to wait 5 more minutes :)

Comment: We've been too fast :-)

Answer (score 2):

First you don't have `args`:

```
class Family(names: String*) {
  def familySize(): Int = names.length
}
```

You have a couple of options:

1) Simple equality operator

```
val family1 = new Family("Mom", "Dad", "Sally", "Dick")
family1.familySize() == 4
```

2) In [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) there is a JavaScript like typesafe equality operator:

```
val family1 = new Family("Mom", "Dad", "Sally", "Dick")
family1.familySize() === 4
```

which throws an exception if operands have different types

3) Different test libraries like: [Scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/), [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) or [Scalacheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck). For example in ScalaTest with must matchers:

```
family1.familySize must equal (4)
```

Comment: Changed 4 to 6 and same thing. `scala filename.scala` just returns nothing.